# How can you create a line graph that the same line has two different colors in matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have a regular line graph

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
plt.plot(db['month_date'], db['quantity'], alpha=0.7)                
plt.ylabel('quantity')
plt.title('Quantity cards ')
plt.show()
```

This generates a normal line graph with a blue line, is there a way that the last three values of quantity are highlithed in a different color? So the normal Blue line and the last three values being red perhaps. If any one can help I would appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by last three values, last three values based on the x-axis? Or the y-axis. Anyway, have a look at this.

[Example of multi-colored lines in Matplotlib documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/multicolored_line.html)

Comment: please ["Provide context for links"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: I'd say the last three values of the y-axis If you know how to do that change directly I would appreciate it but if not I'll take your answer cause yeah that is pretty much what I am looking for Thank you very much J.W Ngo.

Comment: >I'd say the last three values of the y-axis 

That would be the boundary norm part of the example instead of continuous norm.